# How to get id of any page in codeigniter controller

Tags: codeigniter, controller

I am new in Codeigniter.

How to get id of any below page like in codeigniter controller.

www.abc.com/about-us - page

www.abc.com/blog/hello-world - blog details page

www.abc.com/city - Categories

www.abc.com/search - where pass all the input field

Please help me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

code your model like this

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Blog_model extends MY_Model {

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
?>
```

and controller like

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Blog extends MY_Controller {

    protected $per_page=1;
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('blog_model');
    }

    public function index($page=1){
        $page = $page-1;
        if($page<0){
            $page =0;
        }
        $where = ' status = ?';
        $where_data = array(1);
        $rs = $this->blog_model->__select('blogsTablename','count(*) as total_count', $where,$where_data);
        $record = $rs->result();
        $total_row = $record[0]->total_count;
        $this->data['lists'] = $this->blog_model->__select('blogsTablename','*',$where,$where_data,' blog_id desc',$page*$this->per_page,$this->per_page,3);
        $this->load->view('template/header.php');
        $this->load->view('template/navbar.php',array('active_tab'=>'blog'));
        $this->load->view('blog',$this->data);
        $this->load->view('template/footer.php');

    }
}
?>
```

and in routes.php add line

```
$route['blog/(:any)'] = 'blog/index/$1';
```

Comment: and if you want to add a detail page  then make another  view page as detail     and add function in your controller like

Comment: public function detail($blog_id) {
  $this->data['result'] =  $this->blogs_model->get($blog_id);
  $this->load->view('template/header.php');
  $this->load->view('template/navbar.php');
  $this->load->view('detail.php',$this->data);
  $this->load->view('template/footer.php');
 }

Comment: **and in model**       public function get($blog_id){
  $sql ="select * from blogTablename where blog_id = ?";
  $rs = $this->db->query($sql,array($blog_id));
  $record = $rs->result();
  return (array)$record[0];
 }